# Problems testing ML model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have recently been working on a machine learning model and have been trying to test it using a specific piece of code. Unfortunately, I have encountered some issues as I keep receiving an error message every time I attempt to run the code. I have invested a lot of time and effort into trying to resolve the issue but nothing seems to work. I have searched for solutions online and tried various methods but to no avail.

Could anyone offer some advice or guidance? I

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Function to load and prepare an image for use in the model
def prepare_image(image_path):
    # Ladda bilden
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    # Ändra storleken på bilden till 180x180
    img = img.resize((180, 180))
    # Konvertera bilden till en numpy-array och skala värdena till intervallet [0, 1]
    img_arr = np.array(img) / 255.0
    # Lägg till en extra dimension för att skapa en batch med en bild
    img_arr = np.expand_dims(img_arr, axis=0)
    return img_arr

# Specify the path to the saved model
model_path = 'C:/Users/wilme/OneDrive/Skrivbord/OL-Kod-mapp/ML-modell/my_trained_model.h5'

# Load the trained model
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)

# Enter the path to the image you want to make a prediction on
image_path = 'C:/Users/wilme/OneDrive/Skrivbord/karttecken-model/Stig/Stig_3.png'

# Load and prepare the image to be used in the model
img_arr = prepare_image(image_path)

# Use the model to make a prediction on the image
predictions = model.predict(img_arr)

# Display the predicted name of the map character
predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions[0])
class_names = ['Stig', 'Back', ...] 
print('Det förutsagda namnet på karttecknet är:', class_names[predicted_label])
```

**When I test my code to test my model I get this error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\wilme\OneDrive\Skrivbord\OL-Kod-mapp\ML-modell\Ai-modell-test.py",
> line 22, in 
> model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)   File "C:\Users\wilme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\saving\saving_api.py",
> line 212, in load_model
> return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(   File "C:\Users\wilme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py",
> line 70, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   File "C:\Users\wilme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional\base_conv.py",
> line 416, in _get_input_channel
> raise ValueError( ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. The input_shape received is (None, None, None,
> None), where axis -1 (0-based) is the channel dimension, which found
> to be `None`.

**Don't know if it could be a bug in the ML model code that is causing this error.**

**Here is my ML model's code**

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from PIL import Image

# Specify the path where you want to save the model
model_path = 'C:/Users/wilme/OneDrive/Skrivbord/OL-Kod-mapp/ML-modell/my_trained_model.h5'

# Function to remove white from an image
def remove_white(img):
    # Ladda bilden
    im = Image.open(img)
    # Konvertera till RGBA (för att stödja transparenta pixlar i PNG-bilden)
    im = im.convert("RGBA")
    # Hämta pixlarna
    data = im.getdata()
    # Skapa en tom lista
    newData = []
    # Loopa igenom alla pixlar
    for pixel in data:
        # Om pixeln är vit, ersätt med transparent
        if pixel[0] == 255 and pixel[1] == 255 and pixel[2] == 255:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newData.append(pixel)
    # Spara den nya bilden
    im.putdata(newData)
    im.save(img)


# Enter the path to your main folder
data_dir = r'C:\Users\wilme\OneDrive\Skrivbord\karttecken-model'

# Loop through the images and remove white
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            remove_white(file_path)
# Function to load and preprocess images
def preprocess_image(file_path, height, width):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)  # använd decode_png istället för decode_jpeg
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [height, width])
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return img

# Create a training and a validation set
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

val_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_ds = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    target_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='sparse')

val_ds = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    target_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='sparse')

# Build the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=10)

# Save the trained model to the specified path
model.save(model_path)
```

I was under the impression that when I ran the code, the image I provided as an input would be correctly identified and marked as a ‘path’. However, when I executed the code, an error message appeared and the image was not processed as expected. I am unsure of what went wrong and am seeking assistance in resolving this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As given in the [keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) guide, the missing channel which the error is prompting towards, can be given as either 1 or 3 as the `color_mode` argument. Hence the input format expected is (img_width, img_height, channel).